# Saving info to user in Parse iOS 9

Tags: parse-platform, ios9

So I'm trying to save the location, a display name and an image file to Parse, I was successful in saving the image before the iOS 9 update but now I get an error that the parse file is too large. It's just one of the images from the image picker. The display name saved the first time I tried but not on the second and the location doesn't at all. Thanks for the help!

```
func saveUserInfo() {

    //saves picture data to user

    let pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImageView.image!)

    let file = PFFile(name: "image", data: pictureData!)

    file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

        if success {

        self.user.setObject(file, forKey: "profilePicture")
        self.user.saveInBackground()

        }

        else {
            print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    //saves geo point to user (location)

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            self.user.setObject(geoPoint!, forKey: "location")
            self.user.saveInBackground()
        }

        else {
            print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }

    //saves display name

        let displayName = self.displayName.text

        self.user.setObject(displayName!, forKey: "displayName")
        self.user.saveInBackground()
    }
}
```

method to get geopoint which works

```
func getParseGeoPoint() {

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

        self.userGeoPoint = geoPoint
        }

        else if let error = error {

            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }

}
```

EDITED:

I try saving them all at once but the app still crashes

```
func saveUserInfo() {

    //saves picture data to user

    let pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImageView.image!)

    let file = PFFile(name: "image", data: pictureData!)

    file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

        if success {

        self.user.setObject(file, forKey: "profilePicture")
        self.user.setObject(self.userGeoPoint!, forKey: "location")
        self.user.setObject(self.displayName.text!, forKey: "displayName")

        self.user.saveInBackground()

        }

        else {
            print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save all the data to your user object in one go ?? Add all the data to your user object in geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground success closure and upload them in a single save.
Also the maximum size for a PFFile to upload to parse is only 10 MB, so check the size of your file.

Comment: Okay I edited above, it's still crashing though. 

I have it getting the geoPoint when the view loads and then setting it to a global property which I save when the user saves their profile, that should be okay, right? 

Thanks again!

Comment: You do not need to upload your file first. If you assign a PFFile to your object, it will be uploaded automatically when you save that object. The other issue is why do you access your user object via self ?? Your user object is accessible everywhere using PFUser.currentUser() method